# How to Display Information to a table dynamically from an api

Tags: javascript, html, api, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show some songs from an album API dynamically on a page but it is refusing to display. If you can help me solve the problem I will appreaciate.

This is the link to the github: https://github.com/jruto/stackoverflowhelp

This problem is in the javascript file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Several issues.

track.data gave error too

```js
/** @format */
window.addEventListener("load", getSongs)

function getSongs() {
  fetch("https://striveschool-api.herokuapp.com/api/deezer/album/75621062")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((obj) => {
      showSongs(obj)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err.message))
}


function showSongs(album) {
  const displaySongs = document.getElementById("artist-songs")
  displaySongs.innerHTML = `
            <div class="table-body mt-3">
            <div class="d-flex hash">
                <h6 class="text-light">1</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex cover title">
                <div class="cover-son">
                    <img src="${album.cover_small}" width="45" />
                </div>
                <div class="co">${album.tracks.data.map(({title}) => title).join('<br/>')}
                    
                    <br />
                    <a id="a2" href="">${album.artist.name}</a>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex album">
                <span class="text-light album">${album.title}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex date-added">
                <span class="text-light">${album.release_date}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex duration">
                <span class="text-light">${album.duration}</span>
            </div>
        </div>`

}
```

```html
<div id="artist-songs"></div>
```